# AssertTrue vs AssertEquals for ints

Tags: junit

Should we use assertEquals or assertTrue for comparing primitive types specifically ints? 
Is there a preference, if so why ? I'd like to know the pros and cons of each approach.

Comment: Try them both, which of the two will give you a more helpful message if the assertion fails? This will be your answer.

Comment: Looks like a perfectly valid question to me.

Answer (score 24):

`assertEquals()` gives a useful default error message on failure, like "expected X but got Y", but `assertTrue()` can't. Use the more specific applicable method here, which is `assertEquals()`.

Answer (score 3):

assertEquals() is to test the equality of your expected value with the returning value. Whereas assertTrue() is to check for a condition. Having said that, you can also say

If you have a condition like.

```
String x = "abc";
String y = "abc";

assertEquals(x, y);
```

You can also change it to

```
assertTrue(x.equals(y));
```

It is just another way of asserting what you expect.