# How to test an int has been incremented using Junit?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, int, boolean

I have the following method that I would like to test, it simply increments an `int` if a `Boolean` condition is true:

```
 public void incrementIfConditionMet(Boolean personCheckedIn) {

    int peopleInHotel=0;

    if (personCheckedIn==true){

         peopleInHotel++

     }

}
```

I am very new to unit testing in Java. How can I `unit test` this to check if the int has been incremented or not?

Comment: Unless it's a property or a return value, how would you access it? You would need to place it somewhere where it could be accessed, like making a public getter or putting it as a return value

Comment: I am unsure what you mean, please give a code example?

Comment: You should test the public api of the class. if you have a getPeopleInHotel function, you should be able to assertEquals(getPeopleInHotel(), expected);

Comment: Your code as is is incrementing a variable that is only within your method.  After you leave the method your variable disappears and it doesn't matter what value it is anymore

Comment: You cannot test method's local variables.

Comment: @JohannisK please give example of why this is advisable?

Comment: @Nikem ok what is the work a round for this, what way can I test the int has been incremented?

Comment: @java123999 read the other comments. Everyone is stating the same... you can't test if the increment works if you don't have access to the variable you're testing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently your value of `peopleInHotel` cannot be accessed outside the method, as it was created internally. If you want to access it, you should do the following:

```
private int peopleInHotel=0;

public int getPeopleInHotel() {
    return peopleInHotel;
}

public void incrementIfConditionMet(Boolean personCheckedIn) {
    if (personCheckedIn){
         peopleInHotel++
    }
}
```

Now in your test class, you can check by calling `getPeopleInHotel();`

So the test case would be:

```
int initalValue = classInstance.getPeopleInHotel();
classInstance.incrementIfConditionMet(true);
assertEquals(classInstance.getPeopleInHotel(), initalValue +1);
```

This would also fix your issue where you don't keep the value once the method has been ran. At the moment, in your current code setup, your variable of `peopleInHotel` is discarded after you've finished with the method.

Comment: OK thanks, but how do I write the test to check for the int?

Comment: It's in the example... assertEquals(getPeopleInHotel(), expectedQuantity);  You should look at some tutorials if you don't know how to implement this. in this example, you would create an instance, call incrementIfConditionMet(false), assert with expectedQuantity 0, then call incrementIfConditionMet(true), then assert with expectedQuentity 1

Comment: I've updated the test case, you need to get the previous value, and then check it against the new value after you've ran your method

Comment: Hint: there is only one assert that one really needs: *assertTrue* ... as soon as you get used to that one, you will never ever look back to any of the other asserts.

Comment: @Jägermeister why do you feel this is the only assert that is used?

Comment: It's a different way of doing things, it depends on what you want to do. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20990524/asserttrue-vs-assertequals-for-ints)

Comment: @java123999 What I am saying is: *assertThat* can be used instead of any of the other asserts. The point is that *assertThat* creates much better error messages for example; and it is able to directly compare all kinds of objects, even collections. And this is not a "feeling"; but what I do each day in practice. I do not need any other assert any more.

Comment: Now you've changed what you said in the previous comment. Did you meant `assertTrue` or `assertThat`? I would agree with the usage of `assertThat`, but not `assertTrue`. For more reading on that, [see here](https://objectpartners.com/2013/09/18/the-benefits-of-using-assertthat-over-other-assert-methods-in-unit-tests/) @java123999

Answer (score 1):

```
int peopleInHotel=0;

public void incrementIfConditionMet(Boolean personCheckedIn) {
    if (personCheckedIn==true){

         peopleInHotel++

    }
}

public int getPeopleInHotel() { //test the returned value after you've incremented
    return peopleInHotel;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
public class Hotel {
    private int peopleInHotel = 0;

    //a constructor...

    public int getPeopleInHotel() {

        return this.peopleInHotel;

    }

 public void incrementIfConditionMet(Boolean personCheckedIn) {
      if (personCheckedIn==true){
             peopleInHotel++
      }
 }
}
```

In your Unit-Test, you now can do something like that:

```
//defining your TestCase 
Hotel hotel = new Hotel();
int initValue = hotel.getPepleInHotel();
hotel.incrementIfconditionmet(true);
assertEquals(hotel.getPeopleInHotel(),initValue+1);
```